# Horizontal Scroll View not working for HDPI devices

Tags: android-imageview, horizontalscrollview, android-scrollview

I have `HorizontalScrollView` which has image whose size is 2000x650. Its coming well in xhdpi devices. I tried in nexus as well as s3. but when i run the same in hdpi device it does not scroll well and even many times the complete image does not show up also.

Note: xhdpi has different set of resolution and 2000x650 is for hdpi

Comment: I have tried fillviewport= true but that also dint work.